# RVM+Apache+Passenger+Bundler disharmony . Error 404 on SubUri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, rvm, http-status-code-404, passenger

I've spent all day trying to figure out what was the problem with my SubUri. It basically  runs two rails applications in a webserver, the first one, *myapp1*, runs on the root, and the second one, *myapp2*, runs on /api/v1.

The problem is that when I start the server, only the *myapp1*, on the root of the website works, the *myapp2* on /api/v1 of the webserver returns a 404 error.

I think that it's a problem with the gems, that passenger is not using the gems of *myapp2*, that stay on the folder *shared* (due to capistrano), but when looking for how to solve this with RVM, Bundle and Passenger I get that only a *'Require "Bundler/Capistrano"'* on the deploy would solve, but that does not help.

I have no idea about what to do. **Please**, can someone give me a little help here?

**Apache configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.com
  DocumentRoot /home/deploy/myapp1/current/public
  RailsBaseURI /
  <Directory /home/deploy/myapp1/current/public>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

 RailsBaseURI /api/v1
    <Directory /home/deploy/myapp1/current/public/myapp2/v1/current/public>
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**The error in the /var/log/apache2/error.log:**

```
[Tue Jan 22 14:36:52 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Jan 22 14:36:53 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with S$
```

Comment: Is your second app contained in your public folder of the first app? `/home/deploy/myapp1/current/public/myapp2/v1/current/public`. I also think you want to move the `RailsBaseURI` lines into the respective `Directory` blocks.

Comment: Yes, my second app is in the public folder of the first. Didn't understood what you meaned about the RailsBaseUri, can you explain more?

Comment: I assumed the `RailsBaseURI` could not be under the `VirtualHost` multiple times, but apparently it can, so you can ignore that. I imagine having your `myapp2` inside the public folder of `myapp1` could be causing issues. You might consider moving `myapp2` into `/home/deploy` if you can.

Comment: Actually, _myapp2_ is in /home/deploy, but the folder v1 has a symlink to it, as the following documentation recomends: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying%5Frails%5Fto%5Fsub%5Furi

But I tried doing it directly, as you sad, with:
   `RailsBaseURI /api/v1
      <Directory /home/deploy/avante-api/current/public>
          Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>`

But that didn't worked too :(

Comment: folder permissions also come into picture and must be checked..